# ASP.Net 5 (vnext) how to queue background task and access ApplicationServices

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Is it possible to queue a background task and access ApplicationServices to resolve my dependencies in Asp.Net 5 (vnext)?

I'm trying to write a background task that runs every 10 seconds which will query some data and update the MemoryCache.  So I need to resolve IMemoryCache but can figure out how to access the ApplicationServices to resolve it.

Comment: Can you post your source code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the `ServiceProvider` by using the `CallContextServiceProvider` similar to what we did [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Testing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Testing/TestPlatformHelper.cs#L12-L16).

As for background task, there is no out of the box solution. You can try using some threads but you must be careful to keep your server alive if there are no requests. Another option is to use [WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

Comment: Nooo, pass the service provider in to your background task

Comment: Working url: https://github.com/aspnet/Testing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Testing/TestPlatformHelper.cs#L12-L16